# React Native : multiple renders at fetching data with useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having two problems my code.
The first  is that data is undefined, i'm not fetching data from the API.
The seccond is that the hook useEffect it's not working as it should, like componendidmount, and it's on a loop re rendering the coponent.
this is my code :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetch = async () =>{
    try{
      let data = await fetch("https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot", {method: 'GET'});
      let json = await data.json();
      setUsers(json);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log("Im catching the error");
      console.log(err);
      setUsers([]);
      setLoading(false);
    }


  }

  useEffect(() => {
   fetch();
  },[])



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading?<><Text>Loading...</Text></>:<Text>Data fetched</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can't see much wrong, maybe it's the name of the 'fetch' function is clashing with the one from the `fetch` API?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what was going on, kinda funny.

Answer (score 3):

```
....    
const fetch = async () =>{
....
```

fetch method is calling itself, try to change method name